# How to decide which field should return in REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In the Sharepoint website, I have a list called 'publication groups', whose contenty type is A.

I use this url to get the properties of a item.
https://something.com/myweb//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('publication groups')/items?$filter= Title eq 'Sunday'

I find in the xml result, it doesn't contain some field of this item. Actually A content type contains a field called Project, but I cannot get this field in the xml.

Is there anywhere to set the configuration? Thanks.

Edit:

I tried with this url: https://something.com/myweb//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('publication groups')/items?$filter= Title eq 'Sunday'&$select=*,Project
Then I got this error

[image]

I went to the content type setting to see what fields it includes, but I see project there. What may be wrong? Why cannot I get this field if it belongs to Publication group?

[image]

**Edit2:**

I resolved this problem. Why I get the "The field or property project does not exist" error is that I should use the internal name of project field, not the show name. The url should be like this:
https://pubcenter-dev1.sp.srv.volvo.com/robinlab//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('publication%20groups')/items?$select=vppc_ProjectLookupId

Firstly, I need to get the internal name of this project field.

Comment: Try using `https://something.com/myweb//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('publication groups')/items?$filter= Title eq 'Sunday'&$select=*,Project`

Comment: Hi. I notice that you add '$select=*,Project' at the end of the url. Is it poject not included in * ? I suppose that * means it shall return every field of the item.

Comment: Yes, * is for selecting all items. Even after selecting all items, some items are not returned due to performance reasons. That is why, Project column is explicitly selected.

Comment: Hi, uberz91. Thanks very much. But now I could still not get the project field in the response xml file. Could please see my edit? Thanks!

Comment: Hi uberz91. Can you move your comments to the Answer area, so I can mark it as Answer?

Comment: Glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `https://something.com/myweb//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('publication groups')/items?$filter= Title eq 'Sunday'&$select=*,Project`. Judging from OP's edit, apparently, Project wasn't the internal name of the field. Using the correct internal name gave the results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention name of fields which you want to get in result in parameter **$select**

Example

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Languages')/items?$select=Title,LanguageScope,LanguageType
```

Source: [Link](https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/53/)

Comment: Hi Khamar. As I suppose, if I don't use the select key word, it should return all the fields of the items. Is it wrong???